# Prestashop list of categories by name

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using Prestashop and i want to show category listing filter by alphabet order by name.

I have multilangual site

http://online-dental.net/en/1448-alloys

Here i am showing default caterogie list on sidebar. 
Can anybody tell me how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from the configuration page of the Module "Categories block".